# creating a line between two UIlabels using the long press gesture recognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

i am developing a ER diagram editor, i have a bunch of draggable UILabels but all of them have the same name. i want to be able to create a line between two UIlabels when both are pressed together using the long press gesture recognizer. any help will be most appreciated

Comment: By the way, you say that they "all have the same name." What do you mean?

Comment: @Rob they are duplicate labels with different texts of a sentence in them, so i found a way to create multiple labels with different texts in them, so they share the same UIlabel name..for instance

        
        UILabel *labelText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, yVal, 200.0f, 60.0f)];
        labelText.text = sentence;
        labelText.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        labelText.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
        labelText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         labelText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:19.0f];

Comment: @Rob exactly, i mean variable name.. thats exactly where the problem is, since they have the same variable name, i dont have an idea to identify them. if you could write it in code, i would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your long press gesture on the superview shared by these two labels, e.g.:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *twoTouchLongPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                                action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
twoTouchLongPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:twoTouchLongPress];
```

You can then write a gesture handler:

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        CGPoint location0 = [gesture locationOfTouch:0 inView:gesture.view];
        CGPoint location1 = [gesture locationOfTouch:1 inView:gesture.view];

        if ((CGRectContainsPoint(self.label0.frame, location0) && CGRectContainsPoint(self.label1.frame, location1)) ||
            (CGRectContainsPoint(self.label1.frame, location0) && CGRectContainsPoint(self.label0.frame, location1)))
        {
            NSLog(@"success; draw your line");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"failure; don't draw your line");
        }
    }
}
```

---

In the updated comments, you suggest that you're creating a local `UILabel` variable, and then adding the resulting label to the view. That's fine, but you really want to maintain a backing model, that captures what you're doing in the view. For simplicity's sake, let me assume that you'll have array of these labels, e.g.:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *labels;
```

Which you then initialize at some point (e.g. `viewDidLoad`):

```
self.labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then as you add labels to your view, add a reference to them in your array:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, yVal, 200.0f, 60.0f)]; 
label.text = sentence; 
label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
label.layer.borderWidth = 0.0; 
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:19.0f];
[self.view addSubview:label];

[self.labels addObject:label];
```

Then, your gesture can do something like:

```
- (UILabel *)labelForLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
    for (UILabel *label in self.labels)
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(label.frame, location))
            return label;                                // if found one, return that `UILabel`
    }
    return nil;                                          // if not, return nil
}

- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        CGPoint location0 = [gesture locationOfTouch:0 inView:gesture.view];
        CGPoint location1 = [gesture locationOfTouch:1 inView:gesture.view];

        UILabel *label0 = [self labelForLocation:location0];
        UILabel *label1 = [self labelForLocation:location1];

        if (label0 != nil && label1 != nil && label0 != label1)
        {
            NSLog(@"success; draw your line");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"failure; don't draw your line");
        }
    }
}
```

Frankly, I'd rather see this backed by a proper model, but that's a more complicated conversation beyond the scope of a simple Stack Overflow answer. But hopefully the above gives you an idea of what it might look like. (BTW, I just typed in the above without assistance of Xcode, so I'll apologize in advance for typos.)